# eclipse kepler scriptlet formatter about "<%"

Tags: eclipse, jsp, scriptlet

I would like to know how to format the scriplet code in a JSP file, here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function modifyClick(index) {

var editModify = "<td>"+<%=Site.getFieldUIName(Site.field.site_name.name())%>+ "</td>";
```

after I format this file by type <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F</kbd>, the code will change to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function modifyClick(index) {

var editModify = "<td>"
    +
<%=Site.getFieldUIName(Site.field.site_name.name())%>
+ "</td>";
```

Where can I edit this format style for the `<%`, I don't want it always to create a line. 
I have try to find and test the formatter style in JavaScript/web html configuration, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating the JSP code as if its a Javascript string variable.  That's going to be a syntax error in your browser.  You should just do:

```
var editModify = "<td><%=Site.getFieldUIName(Site.field.site_name.name())%></td>";
```

Or, if you want, wrap it in quotes to make it end up as a Javascript string literal:

```
var editModify = "<td>" + "<%=Site.getFieldUIName(Site.field.site_name.name())%>" + "</td>";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I knew that error after some hours later. It seems a possible solution you mention about my question. I will try it to check if there is any other need.